# Multiple markers at this line - String cannot be resolved to a variable - Syntax error on token "food", delete

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I am having this errors:
1- Multiple markers at this line    - String cannot be resolved to a variable   - Syntax error on token "food", delete

2- Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "detail", delete 
     this token
    - String cannot be resolved to a variable

I marked these lines with ** in NewPortlet.java

. Below are my two related files

NewPortlet.java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Constants;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;


public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

  public static String VIEW_JSP ="/html/new/view.jsp";

  @Override
  public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse ) throws IOException, PortletException {
    //renderRequest
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
  }

  public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)  throws IOException, PortletException {
    String cmd = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, Constants.CMD);
        try {
          if (cmd.equals(Constants.ADD)){

            String food = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "food");
            String detail = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "detail");

            long userId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment();
            User user_= UserLocalServiceUtil.createUser(userId);

         ** user_.setFood(food);
         ** user_.setDetail(detail);
            user_.setCreateDate(new Date());

            UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user_ , false);
            SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"food-added-succesfuly");
          }
        }catch (SystemException e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated Catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
  }
}
```

and my service builder

```
<entity name="Food" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="foodId" type="long" primary="true" />

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="food" type="string" />
        <column name="detail" type="string" />
        <column name="createDate" type="new Date()" />
    ...
```

Comment: So which line is "this line"?

Comment: i marked them with ** in NewPortlet.ava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add Food entity but you have used user entity instead.
User entity does not have any attribute/column as food or detail.

To add Food entity you have to use code as below.

```
long userId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(Food.class); 
Food foodEntry_=FoodLocalServiceUtil.createFood(userId); 
foodEntry_.setFood(food); 
foodEntry_.setDetail(detail); 
foodEntry_ .setCreateDate(new Date()); 
FoodLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(foodEntry_ , false); 
SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"food-added-succesfuly");
```